# Jmeter return Error in pattern: '(?<=lang=")(.+?)(?=")'

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am playing with regex in Jmeter, and with some reason it returns an error for the pattern `(?<=lang=")(.+?)(?=")`

I did request to [www.microsoft.com/en-us](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us) where I got

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
```

So I wanted to get `en-US` but I got the error when I use inside Regular Expression Extractor this "?<=". What is really weird as it works properly in python, and in view results Tree element when I use to search in the Response body with regular exp.
Who faced a simular issue, and how to fix it?

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: Jmeter [doesn't support lookbehind](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars). Perhaps you can match all of them, then extract the first group: [`lang="(.+?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/3hdvva/1). However, parsing HTML with regex is a no-no. I don't know Jmeter, but I believe that there are better ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Don't worry, in the current case I can use regex to parse the response(here it will be like a text), the problem is "Note that (?<=regexp) - lookbehind - is not supported.". That I missed. Thanks, @InSync, next time I will go to check the documentation first...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that (?<=regexp) -  - is not supported in Jmeter. So the only way is to use groups
[image: lookbehind]